# wprintf portable code for Linux and Windows

Tags: c, linux, windows, printf, stdout

I have Windows Code which needs to be ported to Linux.

Windows uses a lot of wprintf_s function, for example.

```
wprintf_s(L"Not enough input parameters. See usage statement below.\n\n");
```

We don't have wprintf_s in Linux, as the parameters are same, I use the below statement to convert wprintf_s to wprintf

```
#define wprintf_s wprintf
```

But I am having a problem, wprintf in Linux is only printing one character for this statement.

```
wprintf_s(L"Failed to %u. [%s]: %s\n",
                ucID,
                GetStringErrorName(eError),
                GetStringErrorDescription(eError));
```

Modifying %s to %ls will give me the full string. But this will make me to add a lot of below

```
#ifdef _WIN32 
wprintf_s(L"Failed to %u. [%s]: %s\n",
                    ucID,
                    GetStringErrorName(eError),
                    GetStringErrorDescription(eError)); 
#elif __linux__
wprintf_s(L"Failed to %u. [%ls]: %ls\n",
                    ucID,
                    GetStringErrorName(eError),
                    GetStringErrorDescription(eError)); 
#endif
```

Can you guys please provide a better approach in this problem. Thanks.

Comment: You can use `"%ls"` in Windows as well (see [this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=vs-2019#argument-size-specification)). Which is the correct way (according to the C standard) to print `wchar_t` strings.

Comment: So, the best approach is to replace all %s to %ls.

Comment: That's what I would suggest. :)

Comment: `Windows uses a lot of wprintf_s function` it's your code that uses that function. On Windows you can still use printf